# ATL GUI Tutorials

Tags: user-interface, atl

I'm working on ATL GUI design. I need some tutorials, books about this topic. Can you recommend me a webpage or book?

I have to use ATL, because my application will not only work on a(n) [x] machine. And the resources of the machines are limited, so I have to use ATL. I can't include lots and lots of header files/classes/frameworks and stuff. I know there are lots of possibilities about GUI design. I know there are lots of options. I need ATL.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GUI you typically use [`WTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163305.aspx). ATL support for GUI is limited, and only offers you windows, dialogs, ActiveX controls and hosting. WTL extends this by offering control wrappers, utility types, frame/view model etc.

You will find great samples for both ATL and WTL at

- http://wtl.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.viksoe.dk/code/

Comment: Thank you very much. If you can find more information, please share with me. Thank you very much again. These will help alot.